# Equivalent command for P4 shelve in GIT

Tags: git, perforce

I have migrated from perforce to git . 
Earlier , in p4 , I could make the changes in my tree visible to others using `p4 shelve`. Everyone accessing the same p4 server were able to see my modifications . But now in GIT , I am looking for an equivalent command . I came across `git stash` but this enables changes to be visible only to me .

So , is there a way to make the local changes made  by one user visible to everyone else in git ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Make your commits on a topic branch, push it and then tell everyone to look at that branch.

See for example the [chapter Branching Workflows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) in the Git Book.

Comment: I don't want to push the changes unless the code is reviewed . To get my code reviewed I have to do something like p4 shelve in git

Comment: Why not? Even if you push unreviewed and *broken* code to a topic branch, it won't affect the main repository. The general workflow on git is to push a topic branch, have that reviewed and then merge the code into the `master` branch. It's best not to look for commands "like X in p4" because the way git works is quite different from p4, svn.